# Screen doesn't always shut off on its own

Tags: xorg, kde, chrome, power-management, dpms

It seems like when I have certain web pages focused, my screensaver will kick in, but the screen won't turn itself off. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be? Is there a way to disable whatever is keeping DPMS from kicking in?

Comment: The whatever is probably a movie playing plugin. As far as I know, it's a global X server setting that any client can change (`xset dpms …`) on the command line.

Comment: @Gilles maybe... though I usually leave my browser on Google Reader.

Comment: I know mplayer will do that, and it seems to be permanent; once I've played a video in mplayer my DPMS is disabled until I reenable it or restart. Gilles is probably right, but you'd have to experiment

Comment: @Michael For me mplayer only keeps the screen disabled while playing... my screen will still shut off if it's not playing... well when I'm not using it I always leave smplayer minimized to systray

Comment: @xeno Interesting; must just be something I messed up with my configuration

Comment: @Gilles @Michael doesn't `xset dpms` disable the screensaver too? my screensaver kicks in, my screen just doesn't power off, it keeps running the screensaver.

Comment: `xset dpms` controls the X server feature that powers the screen off. `xset s` controls the X server's built-in screen saver (floating “x” or blanking). It seems that whatever only knows about the X server's built-in feature and not your third-party screensaver. As for your first comment, whatever has to enable dpms again (typically when it exits), I don't think it matters whether it's focused or visible.

Comment: @Michael Mrozek perhaps you have a buggy mplayer version; another case where DPMS settings are mixed up is, when mplayer or a similar program crashes before being able to restore the settings. @xenoterracide *xset +dpms* ... @all why is nobody posting an answer?!?

Comment: @max how am I supposed to use that command to my advantage? I certainly want mplayer to continue to be able to block dpms while playing... it's simply browsers that I'd rather didn't... although tbh, I wish they would block the screensaver while playing (html5/flash)

Comment: Does the same thing happen in Gnome? I know there's an option for this in gnome-control-center under "Screen". I'm not saying you should switch to Gnome, but if it works there, it may give a hint as to where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SELinux enabled? My machine uses the ATI binary blob and it always gets denied to so the monitor is simply black.