# DPMS does not work: the monitor is not switched off

Tags: debian, x11, power-management, dpms

I have a monitor which was properly switched off by my Debian PC when
unused. I attached it to another machine and, this times, it is never
switched off.

In `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, I have:

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Generic Monitor"
        Option          "DPMS"
```

It is recognized when X11 starts:

```
(II) Loading extension DPMS
...
(II) VESA(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off; RGB/Color Display
...
(**) Option "dpms"
(**) VESA(0): DPMS enabled
```

The operating system is Debian 5 (Lenny). The graphics card is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrate
d Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a6f
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 5
        Memory at fe900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
        I/O ports at b080 [size=8]
        Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at fe800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Capabilities: [90] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit- Queue=0/0  Enable-Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
```

X11 is:

```
X.Org X Server 1.4.2
Release Date: 11 June 2008
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux Debian (xorg-server 2:1.4.2-10.lenny2)
Current Operating System: Linux ludwigVII 2.6.26-2-686 #1 SMP Sun Jun 21 04:57:3
8 UTC 2009 i686
Build Date: 08 June 2009  09:12:57AM
```

Comment: [related](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1583/29)?

Comment: Does the monitor switch off if you run `xset dpms force off`? What is the output of `xset q | grep -A1 DPMS`?

Comment: Answers to Gilles' questions are in deleted comments (`xset dpms force off` doesn't work, and the `xset` output is `Standby: 240 Suspend: 450 Off: 900 DPMS is Enabled Monitor is On`). The last comment suggested a hardware problem but never got a reply, so without that I'm going to call this question abandoned and close it

Comment: @Gilles I have this same problem. The monitor turns off briefly (not even for a second) then comes back on and the screen stays blank. I know it turns off because of the LED animation that my monitor does. Almost immediately afterward, the monitor comes back on.

Comment: @doug65536 This question has been abandoned for years. You should ask a new question with all the details of your problem (which may be the same, or may only have similar symptoms).

Comment: @Gilles it is exactly the same as this guy's question. Not interested in asking a "too localized" question. Another bully will come along and stomp on my question then. Why do you say it was "abandoned" when there are zero answers and it was closed as too localized. Looks like SO abandoned this person who asked the question. I wish there were an easy way to protest a question closure.

Comment: @doug65536 This is a troubleshooting question which requires feedback from the person having the problem. The asker of this question stopped providing requested feedback. If you have a similar problem, ask a new question and provide feedback. You can protest a question closure by voting or flagging to reopen or opening a meta discussion. For a question with no answers and where the asker has lost interest, there's very little point in reopening.